# How to loop xml in store procedure

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, xml-parsing

I have a store procedure that returns the below XML:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header />
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:ReportResponse>
      <ns2:responseTitle />
      <ns2:responseBody>
        <ns2:resultRow>
          <ns2:result Name="country" Value="United Kingdom" />
          <ns2:result Name="code" Value="7360" />
        </ns2:resultRow>
        <ns2:resultRow>
          <ns2:result Name="country" Value="France" />
          <ns2:result Name="code" Value="7340" />
        </ns2:resultRow>
      </ns2:responseBody>
    </ns2:ReportResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I want to be able to save the 2 records in the table, how can I get a loop to get the data?

Record 1:
Country=United Kingdom
Code=7360

Record 2:
Country=France
Code=7340

I tried to use this select but it's not returning anything.

```
SELECT 
    Record.value('@Name','VARCHAR')
FROM @XmlResponse.nodes('/Envelope/Body/ReportResponse/responseBody/resultRow')AS TEMPTABLE(Record)
```

Thanks.

Comment: That's invalid XML.  Where is the `ns2' namespace declared?  Also see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/with-xmlnamespaces?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Hi David, I removed it from the tag ReportResponse.

    <ns2:ReportResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.test.com/reports/schemas" xmlns:ns3="http://www.test.com/ws/schemas" xmlns:ns4="http://www.test.com/ws/mobile/schemas" xmlns:ns5="http://www.test.com/ws/newmobile/schemas">

Comment: Also, stop declaring your data types without a length/scale/precision. The value of `@Name` is `'country'`; that will **never** fit in a `varchar(1)`. [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=16f10514c57537f7ad4a6e0df9f6eb86)

Comment: Hi Lamu, thanks for your answer re the best practices. It was a snippet for something I don't have working - of course, will it be improved/corrected. My question is regarding how can I get the values, can you help me on that?

Comment: Not when the XML is invalid, @SérgioPaulino  no. Parsing XML when it isn't XML isn't a very difficult task. you need to fix the XML first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
declare @doc xml = '
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header />
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:ReportResponse xmlns:ns2="http://whatever">
      <ns2:responseTitle />
      <ns2:responseBody>
        <ns2:resultRow>
          <ns2:result Name="country" Value="United Kingdom" />
          <ns2:result Name="code" Value="7360" />
        </ns2:resultRow>
        <ns2:resultRow>
          <ns2:result Name="country" Value="France" />
          <ns2:result Name="code" Value="7340" />
        </ns2:resultRow>
      </ns2:responseBody>
    </ns2:ReportResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as soap ,
                    'http://whatever' as ns2)
SELECT 
    Record.value('(ns2:result[@Name="country"])[1]/@Value','VARCHAR(20)') Country,
    Record.value('(ns2:result[@Name="code"])[1]/@Value','int') Code
FROM @doc.nodes('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns2:ReportResponse/ns2:responseBody/ns2:resultRow')AS TEMPTABLE(Record)
```

outputs

```
Country              Code
-------------------- -----------
United Kingdom       7360
France               7340

(2 rows affected)
```

Comment: Great, it's working now. Thank you - much appreciated.